# Why is Math.floor(Math.random() * n) better than Date.now() % n to choose a random number between [0, n]?

Tags: javascript, random

I have been using `Math.floor(Math.random() * someArray.length)` for years to choose a random element in an array. I have always wondered why it is better than `Date.now() % someArray.length`. The latter seems to me much less error prone and must be faster (though, I haven't actually benchmarked it).

Notes:

1. I don't need repeatability.
2. This isn't run in a loop, so the function is called randomly throughout the application.
3. This isn't for a simulation, so "more or less" random is good enough.

Comment: The one is not better than the other, but they are different: one returns a pseudo-random value, the other does not.

Comment: It is somewhat dangerous to consider things equivalent when they are not. It may work for you in this project, but humans tend to generalise very easily; and using this in code that actually does need random numbers is a huge security hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have always wondered why it is better than Date.now() % someArray.length

Dates are significantly more complicated than just `Math.random` - `Math.random` is a method designed *specifically* for creating a random number, and is significantly faster:

```js
const p0 = performance.now();
const n = 3;
for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
  (Date.now() % 3)
}
const p1 = performance.now();
console.log(p1 - p0);
```

vs

```js
const p0 = performance.now();
const n = 3;
for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
}
const p1 = performance.now();
console.log(p1 - p0);
```

There's a noticeable bit of overhead when using Dates - plus Dates aren't exactly random. For example, if you're trying to choose a number between 1 and 1000, and the user happens to try to generate an number every 1 second, the resulting numbers may well all be close together, which probably isn't desirable. (Best not to count on user input timing being random)

If semi-decent randomness, security, and performance aren't *important* goals for your project (which would understandable in a small, casual script), you're free to use `Date.now()` instead, it won't hurt that much, it's just an unusual thing to do and won't be dependably random. If you want *precise, secure* randomness, use [Crypto.getRandomValues()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) instead of `Math.random()`.

Comment: Just a note, if "precise randomness" and "security" **are** important, then don't use Math.random either ;)